# On mobile, mathjax fails to render \geqslant

Tags: bug, mathjax

When I was browsing the Hot Network Questions today, I came across [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/41123/16465) which on my iPhone 4S (iOS 9.1) looks like this:

[image]

On my laptop it renders just fine, and I couldn't find any existing bug reports like this (though it may be hiding under all the "mathjax doesn't work at all" posts).

Comment: +1 though I think you should've posted on meta.SE. I'm not sure when the last bug report happened here $\ldots$ If it doesn't get the attention it deserves you could flag it for migration. Just let it play for a day or two.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Since not all sites have MathJax, I figured I'd start here and let it get migrated if someone was sure it's not unique to this site or that particular answer for some strange reason.

Comment: There are issues with other commands as well (only on mobile and not desktop). `\operatorname`, `\dfrac` and `tfrac`, `\lvert` and `\rvert` just to name a few.

Comment: I believe it's a bug of the ios app, I don't have the problem on Android. Meta would probably be a better place for this question.

Comment: It sounds like they may not have the iOS app configured to load the AMSmath and AMSsymbols extensions, where these macros are defined.